# Dplyr function to match column value to row values and replace it

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have 2 data frames. Data Frame A is [image: Data Frame A] and Data Frame B is[image: Data Frame B]

I want to take the values of column active ident in Data Frame B and input them as a row on the top of Data Frame A in a way where they match up according to column name from Data Frame B

I have tried using dplyr but I cant seem to figure out how to do this in R. Would appreciate any help

Attaching dput(head) for both my files

Cell Labels

```
    structure(list(`hnscc.vp.fibroblasts@active.ident` = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Cluster_0", "Cluster_4", "Cluster_3", 
"Cluster_2", "Cluster_1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("pat01.pre_AAACCTGAGGAGCGAG", 
"pat01.pre_AAACCTGCACTACAGT", "pat01.pre_AAACCTGTCACCGTAA", "pat01.pre_AAATGCCCACTATCTT", 
"pat01.pre_AACCATGAGCATCATC", "pat01.pre_AACCGCGCAGATGGCA"), class = "data.frame")
```

Gene Count Per Cell :

```
    dput(head(Gene_Counts_per_Cell[, c(1:5)]))
structure(list(pat01.pre_AAACCTGAGGAGCGAG = c(1.99399322071276, 
1.5433201979508, 2.4725719042226, -2.59159111384049, 1.56977481481343, 
0.192853860719877), pat01.pre_AAACCTGCACTACAGT = c(2.90248911455912, 
2.27707326162242, 2.12992680712843, -1.44512552229319, 0.541062218328074, 
1.8626908687607), pat01.pre_AAACCTGTCACCGTAA = c(3.99090573935858, 
3.00560247848693, 2.9656947677965, -3.23693215603618, 4.72557633990864, 
0.0247894431208639), pat01.pre_AAATGCCCACTATCTT = c(1.08405270702075, 
-0.884466121620786, 0.500175551980942, -2.28142505510742, 3.97105313918843, 
-1.01130712883293), pat01.pre_AACCATGAGCATCATC = c(4.55944063063621, 
2.43937477176712, 3.93016796802459, -1.92695887361317, 3.16070890309665, 
1.65917938530014)), row.names = c("ACTB", "ACTG1", "ACTN1", "ADAP2", 
"ADM", "ADRB2"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @Abullah Bin Naveed, could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply. Added it to my main post above

Answer (score 0):

This maybe what you are looking for. Note have had to convert the clusters into numeric to ensure type consistency for columns. Use rownames to distinguish between clusters and other numeric data in the columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)


  dfb %>% 
  rownames_to_column("rowname") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rowname, values_from = `hnscc.vp.fibroblasts@active.ident`) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(str_extract(.x, "\\d$")))) %>%
  mutate(cluster = "cluster") %>% 
  column_to_rownames(var = "cluster") %>% 
  bind_rows(dfa)

#>         pat01.pre_AAACCTGAGGAGCGAG pat01.pre_AAACCTGCACTACAGT
#> cluster                  3.0000000                  4.0000000
#> ACTB                     1.9939932                  2.9024891
#> ACTG1                    1.5433202                  2.2770733
#> ACTN1                    2.4725719                  2.1299268
#> ADAP2                   -2.5915911                 -1.4451255
#> ADM                      1.5697748                  0.5410622
#> ADRB2                    0.1928539                  1.8626909
#>         pat01.pre_AAACCTGTCACCGTAA pat01.pre_AAATGCCCACTATCTT
#> cluster                 3.00000000                  3.0000000
#> ACTB                    3.99090574                  1.0840527
#> ACTG1                   3.00560248                 -0.8844661
#> ACTN1                   2.96569477                  0.5001756
#> ADAP2                  -3.23693216                 -2.2814251
#> ADM                     4.72557634                  3.9710531
#> ADRB2                   0.02478944                 -1.0113071
#>         pat01.pre_AACCATGAGCATCATC pat01.pre_AACCGCGCAGATGGCA
#> cluster                   3.000000                          3
#> ACTB                      4.559441                         NA
#> ACTG1                     2.439375                         NA
#> ACTN1                     3.930168                         NA
#> ADAP2                    -1.926959                         NA
#> ADM                       3.160709                         NA
#> ADRB2                     1.659179                         NA
```

- data

```
dfb <- structure(list(`hnscc.vp.fibroblasts@active.ident` = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Cluster_0", "Cluster_4", "Cluster_3", 
                                                                                                 "Cluster_2", "Cluster_1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("pat01.pre_AAACCTGAGGAGCGAG", 
                                                                                                                                                              "pat01.pre_AAACCTGCACTACAGT", "pat01.pre_AAACCTGTCACCGTAA", "pat01.pre_AAATGCCCACTATCTT", 
                                                                                                                                                              "pat01.pre_AACCATGAGCATCATC", "pat01.pre_AACCGCGCAGATGGCA"), class = "data.frame")



dfa <- structure(list(pat01.pre_AAACCTGAGGAGCGAG = c(1.99399322071276, 
                                              1.5433201979508, 2.4725719042226, -2.59159111384049, 1.56977481481343, 
                                              0.192853860719877), pat01.pre_AAACCTGCACTACAGT = c(2.90248911455912, 
                                                                                                 2.27707326162242, 2.12992680712843, -1.44512552229319, 0.541062218328074, 
                                                                                                 1.8626908687607), pat01.pre_AAACCTGTCACCGTAA = c(3.99090573935858, 
                                                                                                                                                  3.00560247848693, 2.9656947677965, -3.23693215603618, 4.72557633990864, 
                                                                                                                                                  0.0247894431208639), pat01.pre_AAATGCCCACTATCTT = c(1.08405270702075, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      -0.884466121620786, 0.500175551980942, -2.28142505510742, 3.97105313918843, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      -1.01130712883293), pat01.pre_AACCATGAGCATCATC = c(4.55944063063621, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         2.43937477176712, 3.93016796802459, -1.92695887361317, 3.16070890309665, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1.65917938530014)), row.names = c("ACTB", "ACTG1", "ACTN1", "ADAP2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "ADM", "ADRB2"), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>